# Im trying to construct a doc file containg Bangla language but the saved docx file doesn't show any character in python docx library

Tags: python, python-docx

```
document = Document()

document.add_heading(header, 0)

document.add_paragraph('বাংলা ভাষা টেক্সট')



document.add_page_break()

document.save('DownloadableFiles\\DOCX_FILES\\'+file_name+'.docx')
```

but the file shows

[image: screenshot of some boxes]

Comment: Please provide a sample of your document, and a wider explanation of the problem

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me if I run this code, stripped down a bit and using the `python-docx` package:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
document.add_paragraph('বাংলা ভাষা টেক্সট')
document.add_page_break()
document.save('test.docx')
```

When I open the resulting document in LibreOffice, I see:

[image: characters that look about right to my ignorant eye]

So I suspect the problem is not with your Python code, but with your Word installation or, more likely, your fonts. Maybe you need to explicitly install or switch to a font that supports these characters.

Comment: thank for you precious time i'll check it out and try to resolve it....

Comment: i checked still gives the same output and i also checked from different pc no difference.